# Insert set numbers to set values

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have the following data set:

```
PARENT_RECORD
5
5
5
6
6
6
7
```

These records go into the thousands.

I have another empty column in which where I want to place a number starting from 100 and for each unique `parent_record` associate the number "100" to it.

For example,
each `parent_record "5"` will have 100 in my other column. Each `parent_record "6"` will then have 101 in the other column and this will continue all the way through the `parent_record` column.

I am using Access but it can be exported into an Excel spreadsheet. 
Anyone know of any functions or any SQL which can help me do this?

Comment: I have kind of implemented this in Access with the autonumber feature but there is no way of adding a "Where" oriented clause which will assign only 100 to the parent_record 5 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use and UPDATE query to do this

```
UPDATE YourTable SET YourField = (parent_record + 95)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking too deep into this and didn't realise it was so simple.

Comment: Thanks is appreciated but not necessary.  If my answer was the best and worked for you, checking my answer as accepted is all the thanks needed.